# Call MVC Action from Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, controller

Is it possible to an call MVC action(Logout) from the jquery setTimeout function?

I have tried the following code:

```
setTimeout(function () { @Html.Action("Logout") }, 150000);
```

Comment: You can make an AJAX call to an MVC whatever and logout from there.

Answer (score 2):

Do you understand the difference between when code runs?

This code:

```
setTimeout(function () { @Html.Action("Logout") }, 150000);
```

Will produce something like this on the client:

```
 setTimeout(function () { <div><a href="">Logout</a></div> }, 150000);
```

Which is completely invalid javascript (regardless what it actually does it will return html normally).

You could do (I think this is right)

```
 setTimeout(function () 
   { 
     window.location = '@Url.Action("Logout","Account")'; 
   }, 150000);
```

Which would produce something like:

```
 setTimeout(function () 
   { 
     window.location = '/Account/Logout'; 
   }, 150000);
```